# Branching in Pyscipopt

Tags: python, optimization, scip

Branching on t_x21 led to this error

> [scip_branch.c:1061] ERROR: cannot branch on variable <t_x21> with fixed domain [-0,0]

So, my guess as to why this did not work is that during presolving, SCIP fixed this variable to be 0 and hence it throws an error if we try to branch on it? Is this correct? (Also, this error occured after a restart)

[Link to scip_branch.c](https://github.com/scipopt/scip/blob/3d229190c1e6768d7c98641aca26d6e709a4f870/src/scip/scip_branch.c#L1061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, branching on a fixed variable does not make much sense. You should check the bounds before selecting a variable as a branching candidate, I suppose.